# Facebook sharer.php url parameter being ignored randomly

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a site with smart-urls that lets you build up a dynamic url based on some user interaction. I devised a button using sharer/sharer.php?u=**someurl**.

EDIT: ** SomeUrl is a shortened-url ( using bit.ly)

The thing is sometimes **someurl** gets ignored and the post links to some other url ( which is the one defined on the og:url of the site). This happens somehow randomly.

```
<a href="http://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=|u|" title="Share this page on facebook" sn="facebook" class="pop share-icon sn=facebook share-icon-facebook"></a>

href = href.replace('|u|',shareHref).replace('|t|',t).replace('|140|',t.substring(0,130))
window.open(href,'t','toolbar=0,resizable=1,status=0,width=640,height=528');
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

So, I've finally switched to FB.ui dialogs. The docs say sharer.php works only with ?u parameter but I've found it impossible to fix the bug mentioned above. If you're struggling with sharer, consider using FB.ui is fairly easy to integrate.